# How to store byte[] in text field in database and retrieve it

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, telerik, arrays

I have a large issue.
I uploaded image and get `byte[]`.
In database I have `NVARCHAR(MAX)` field and it can't be changed.
What ever I do and save in database I can't get it as image later.
I triedn .ToString() doesn't work.
I have tried this:

```
private byte[] GetBytes(string str)
        {
            byte[] bytes = new byte[str.Length * sizeof(char)];
            System.Buffer.BlockCopy(str.ToCharArray(), 0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            return bytes;
        }
static string GetString(byte[] bytes)
        {
            char[] chars = new char[bytes.Length / sizeof(char)];
            System.Buffer.BlockCopy(bytes, 0, chars, 0, bytes.Length);
            return new string(chars);
        }
```

And when I try to put it in `RadBinaryImage` I get nothing.
This is the error:

```
 The provided binary data may not be valid image or may contains unknown header
```

Comment: You MIME encode/decode the bytes in and out of the TEXT field.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You probably want to [encode it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-to-text_encoding), rather than just convert directly.

I've successfully used Radix-64 encoding in the past.  There's a C# method for it, but I haven't used it:

```
Convert.ToBase64String(byteArrayForImage);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dhx0d524.aspx

Then you can use the reverse conversion to get your byte array:

```
Convert.FromBase64String(stringFromDB)
```